# Why was the question about "expected difference of random variables" put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

As I explained in the answer to the question [The metric of the expected difference of random variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/174728/the-metric-of-the-expected-difference-of-random-variables/175751#175751), I don't see any reason for closing it other than simple misunderstanding (to put it mildly) on the part of those who did it. [In spite of OP's disclaimer, what is the starting point of a very interesting recent mathematical development was mistaken for the trivial definition of $L^1$ metric.] If this is indeed the case I invite them to reopen the question, if not then to give their reasons.

**Edit:** The question has been reopened. Those who feel it should have remained closed are invited to give their reasons.

Comment: I think the question was probably just closed by mistake.